# NoRouteToHostException using XmlSlurper in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I am trying to parse an XML file using XmlSlurper.  I have the following code:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
def newIssue = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("1234-export.xml"))
```

Running this gets me:

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host.
```

I am able to do XmlSlurper().parstText( ... ) without problems, and I was able to get the file using:

```
def newFile = new File("1234-export.xml")
```

I still get the no route exception if I try to pass newFile to parse() though.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it looks like the problem was with some header information that the XML file had.